# Android shared transition from Fragment to parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

how I could do a transition from an ImageView in a Fragment to an ImageView in the parent Activity, where the Fragment is.

Background is, that I have just one Activity in my App and a lot of Fragments. So if I change a Fragment to another then I want a shared transition to the Toolbar which is on the Activity.

How is that behavior possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) can help you. If not, post some of your code.

Comment: Thanks for that link, it is a very nice overview of transitions.